# React Native - Expo update cause main no registered and tried to register two same name error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have recently tried to update my React native application from expo 44 to 46 but it cause error

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Router from './src/Router';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The error i am getting is:

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNGestureHandlerButton
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Please find my [github link](https://github.com/sathishdgl96/quizhub/blob/main/package.json)

Answer (score 0):

I believe expo docs are not clear on this:
Don't install **react-native-gesture-handler**,
it already exists in Expo.

*If you are using Expo to build your react native app you do not have to import react-native-gesture-handler from npm or yarn. It is already in the expo package. If you import the package you will experience this error.*

Also, you can check errors on github instead of directly posting question: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/451